# How do I tell reviewers that I have responded to their suggestions?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

Azure DevOps lets a reviewer tell the developer that they have completed their review with the "waiting for the author" flag on a PR review.

But as the developer how can I tell the reviewer "I have finished addressing comments?" They may get a notification for every reply I make to a review comment but typically, we work that a reviewer won't re-review until I've finished addressing all their comments. I can send them a message but it seems like there should be a way to do it from the PR itself.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortenately there is no out-of-the-box method to do this.
These are the only subscription that can be made for code (git) notification:
[image: notification options]

You could however come up with a process flow yourself, some examples:

1. Define that all fixes should be made in one push to the branch. The developer can fix the remark in several commits, but whenever he pushes these commits the notification is send out - triggering the reviewer to look again.

[image: new push notification]

2. Another option is the agreement of a code word or sentence in the commit message, like: rework-complete.
   The reviewer filters out these message in their mail client, to see what PR are up for review again.
3. Alternatively you could alter the status of a PR linked work item.
   *For example:*
   After review, the develop work item is set back to the status: Active.
   Whenever this work item is closed, the review can be done again.
   This will avoid unwanted, out of AzDo, message sending.

Again, no out-of-the-box solution afaik, but I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

PR authors and reviewers can communicate with each other by adding and responding to PR comments. When you review a PR, use comments to point out issues with the proposed changes, suggest changes, and respond to previous comments. Aim for constructive feedback that's precise and easy to understand. Address recipients directly by using their `@username`. Reference work items by using `#workitemID` and other PRs by using `!pullrequestID`.

**Reply to comments**

PR authors should reply to comments to let the reviewers know how they're addressing feedback and suggestions:

1. To reply to a comment, type your response in the **Write a reply** field. Address recipients directly by using their `@username`. Reference work items by using `#workitemID` and other PRs by using `!pullrequestID`.
2. After entering your response, select **Reply & resolve** if your response is final. Otherwise, select **Reply**.

   If you select **Reply & resolve**, the comment status will change to **Resolved**. PR authors can also directly change a comment's status, as described in the next section.

**Change comment status**

New comments initially have an **Active** status, which PR authors update during PR the review process to indicate how they addressed reviewer feedback and suggestions. PR authors can select a comment status from the status dropdown list:

Active: the default status for new comments.

Pending: the issue in this comment is under review and awaits something else.

**Resolved**: the issue in this comment is addressed.

Won't fix: the issue in this comment is noted but won't be fixed.

Closed: the discussion in this comment is closed.

When you have finished addressing comments, you can change all the comment status to **Resolved** and let the reviewers know that you have responded to their suggestions.

You can refer to this document [Review and comment on pull requests - Azure Repos | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/review-pull-requests?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser).

If you want a feature to highlight that all comments have been addressed in the PR, it's recommended that you could submit a suggestion ticket on [Visual Studio Feedback](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest). That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate engineering team and make it more convenient for the engineering team to collect and categorize your suggestions. By the way, you can directly add your vote after you create the suggestion ticket and keep track of this progress there. Voting helps increase the priority of the issue by consolidating customer impact under one feedback.